# Firefox driver jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, groovy, jenkins, geb

I have problem with test on jenkins/

```
go to create new company(CBNPortalRegNewCompSpec)  Time elapsed: 2.365 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"tag name","selector":"html"}
Command duration or timeout: 730 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 20:21:18'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'i386', os.version: '2.6.32-5-686', java.version: '1.6.0_18'
Session ID: 89dde50d-9812-4d77-a2d1-4b4eae055566
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=17.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
Command duration or timeout: 817 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 15:53:30'
System info: os.name: 'FreeBSD', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '8.3-STABLE', java.version: '1.6.0_32'
Session ID: 26cb6541-71ce-43a8-83e6-980a6b7a8e51
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, webdriver.remote.sessionid=26cb6541-71ce-43a8-83e6-980a6b7a8e51, version=17.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:533)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:302)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByTagName(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByTagName.findElement(By.java:320)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:294)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$2.invoke(EventFiringWebDriver.java:101)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver.findElement(EventFiringWebDriver.java:180)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement.call(FindElement.java:47)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement.call(FindElement.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) 
Results :
Tests in error: 
  CBNPortalRegNewCompSpec.go to create new company:49->GebSpec.methodMissing:51 � NoSuchElement
```

But on my local machine(win XP sp3, firefox ver 17.0.1, webdriver 2.28.0, java 1.7_10) test works.

Comment: I guess that `GebSpec.methodMissing:51 � NoSuchElement` line in the stacktrace is self explanatory.

Comment: Did the web server actually see a request from the Selenium run?

Comment: Why are you trying to find the `html` tag?! This is a problem with your test, nothing else. You should show us what your test looks like.